# Change CSS model with button

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova

In my Cordova app, I would like to have 2 buttons :

- Little text : One for load a special class with my div
- Big text : The other for load an another class for my div

It would be for changing the size of the text in my div.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about you're trying since you didn't give much information, but it should point you to the right direction:

```css
.text-lg {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text-sm {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12">    
    <span ng-class="radio">Text</span>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="text-lg" ng-model="radio">Big text
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="text-sm" ng-model="radio">Small text
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```